# mvc3 labelfor subobject

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have two classes :

```
public class foo{
    [Display(Name="Here is my bar")]
    public bar myBar;

    [Display(Name="Here is my name")]
    public string myName;

}

public class bar{
    ...
}
```

I have a view "chooseBar.cshtml" strongly typed of foo.

If I put a @Html.LabelFor(model => model.myName) -> I see "Here is my name" in the label. 
But, if i put a @Html.LabelFor(model => model.myBar) -> I see only "myBar", not the expected "Here is my bar"

How can I use the LabelFor for my subobject ?(i.e displaying "Here is my bar" instead of "myBar" in the label)

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly... going to refer back to this tomorrow if unanswered. I think you have to do something to the class bar to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could decorate `Bar`'s property you want to render with the attribute:

```
public class Bar
{
   [Display(Name="Here is my bar")]
   public string BarName { get; set; }
}
```

And use a custom editor template:

**Bar.cshtml**

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.BarName)
```

**chooseBar.cshtml**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Bar)
```

Could be another way, but i generally always use editor/display templates when i want to render a sub-model.